# How to assert the type of mouse cursor before and onHover on an element in Selenium Webdriver ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

The type of cursor before is 'pointer'. And while onHover the cursor changes its type to  'arrow'. Need to assert that the cursor before and after has the correct types.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Javascript Executor to run a script and get the ideal cursor type on a particular element. Ideally, it is set in cursor css and javascript will fetch it for you, mouse hover is not required for this...

Here is how you can do it (code in ruby)

```
cursor_type = driver.execute_script("return $(<css locator>).css('cursor')");
```

for example on this page, the cursor type becomes a pointer when you hover over the main question which is this   **How to assert the type of mouse cursor before and onHover on an element in Selenium Webdriver ?**

so for this example, here is what you can quickly do in the console tab of developer tools of your browser.

```
console.log($('#question-header a').css('cursor'));
```

Let me know in the commets if there is any problem..

Hope it helps!! :)

Comment: Thank you. This pretty much gave me the hint to write it for WebdriverIO. So will tick as correct answer.